# How do I use FindMinimum with the LevenbergMarquardt method?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

Below is my program. I don't know how to define the function `f` to make it work.

Another question:

When I define `f` as a vector of the form `{x, x*y}` and use

```
FindMinimum[Norm[f], {{x, 1}, {y, 1}}, Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt"]
```

it works. But is `FindMinimum` handling both problems the same way? I mean the norm and the sum? I ask because the solution that I get with `Norm[f]` is `{x -> 3.95915*10^-9, y -> 1.}`, which is not the local minimum obviously.

```
f[x_, y_] := {x, x*y}
FindMinimum[
  Sum[f[x, y][[i]]^2, {i, 1, 2}], {{x, 1}, {y, 1}}, 
  Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt"]
```

> FindMinimum::notlm: The objective function for the method LevenbergMarquardt must be in a least-squares form: Sum[f[i][x]^2, {i, 1, n}] or Sum[w[i] f[i][x]^2, {i, 1, n}] with positive w[i].

Comment: Try `Minimize[Norm[f[x, y]], {x, y}]`?

Comment: @MarcoB I want to use the method "LevenbergMarquardt", and with this method, mathematica wants the function to minimize to be a sum of squares

Answer (score 3):

As described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationGaussNewtonMethods.html), sometimes it is difficult to write the minimand explicitly as a dot product that *Mathematica* will recognize. In that case, you can specify it explicitly:

```
FindMinimum[x^2 + x^2 y^2, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}},
  Method -> {"LevenbergMarquardt", "Residual" -> {x, x y}}
 ]
(* {1.10934*10^-31, {x -> 3.33067*10^-16, y -> 1.}} *)
```